# Vaadin 8 - Download Button for a text file with String content

Tags: scala, stream, vaadin, vaadin8

I want to assign `String` content to a variable and enable the user to download that String as a text file.
I know there is `FileDownloader` from Vaadin 8 which I can use but I don't want static file/image download capability but rather **dynamic String content** which can downloaded a **text file** in the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resource interface in Vaadin, that is used by [`FileDownloader`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/FileDownloader.html) is a bit cumbersome. Especially so for dynamically created content, whose generation you'll want to postpone until user actually clicks the download button, which is very common in typical Vaadin apps.

## Viritin add-on

Thus, I suggest to add [*Viritin* add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/viritin) to your application. Use the `DownloadButton` component from it, which simplifies the usage a lot.

Here is a trivial example:

```
DownloadButton simple = new DownloadButton(out -> {
    try {
        out.write("Foobar".getBytes());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // exception handling
    }
}).withCaption("Simple Download");
```

To see more complete example, refer to [the tests](https://github.com/viritin/viritin/blob/26b52af2d91c532ef695a30379e403ff53ea555b/viritin/src/test/java/org/vaadin/viritin/it/DownloadButtonExample.java) in the Viritin project. From the project you can also see the "raw solution" if you peruse the source code of `DownloadButton` class.

PS. I'm the author of *Viritin*, so kind of biased to suggest its usage, but I have also been working with Vaadin for Vaadin Ltd for over a decade.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution in Scala. We create a `ReportDownloader` component which extends VerticalLayout. It contains a "Download" button which trigger text file download in the browser.

```
import com.vaadin.ui.{Button, VerticalLayout}
import com.vaadin.server._
import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream}

class VaadinStringStream(str : String, browserFileNameSuggestion : String) extends ConnectorResource {

  override def getMIMEType: String = "text/plain"
  override def getFilename: String = browserFileNameSuggestion
  override def getStream: DownloadStream = new DownloadStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes), getMIMEType, getFilename
  )
}

class ReportDownloader extends VerticalLayout{
  val btn = new Button("DOWNLOAD")
  this addComponent btn

  val stream = new VaadinStringStream("This is a sample txt file content", "report.txt")
  new FileDownloader(stream).extend(btn)
}
```

`VaadinStringStream` takes dynamic String content and a suggested filename for the browser as arguments.

Comment: Looks like a valid solution, but the file content is stored to the memory already when the download button is shown. Thus, I suggest to use this kind of solution only if the content of downloaded file is small and there is only a bunch of download links. Otherwise this will cause a heavy memory usage for the server.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I later on changed in-memory String `"This is a sample txt file content"` to a lambda returning a String.  `class VaadinStringStream(str : () => String) extends ConnectorResource` Abandoning Strings and using Streams only would be an even better solution.